# Como hacer que un evento solo se cargue una vez javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas, estoy haciendo una web con jquery y c#.

El problema que tengo es que al clicar en unos menús de la web más de una vez, creo que el contenido html de la página se va cargando una y otra vez. Con esto, al clicar en el menú se repite el evento click() y se clica 2 veces .

Me gustaria saber cómo puedo borrar el script anterior al cargar de nuevo la misma pagina html para que no acabe la página con el mismo script muchas veces. Gracias.

El código completo  es el siguiente:
**Menú Superior**

```
          $(function () {
                $("[id*='gestion_polizas']").click(function () {
                    $("[id*='leftWrapper']").hide();

                    $("[id*='contenido']").load("Polizas/gridPolizas.aspx");
                    //$("[id*='leftWrapper']").load("Recibos/menuLateral_recibos.aspx");

                    //por si tarda al cargar cuando se pulsa el boton
                    //$("[id*='contenido']").load("Cargando.aspx");
                    //setTimeout($("[id*='contenido']").load("JqGridInformatica.aspx"), 2000);
                });
            })
```

**Al clickar en una fila del grid(hace que se abra el menú lateral)**

```
   onSelectRow: function (row_id) {

                          //hago un hide en el formulario anterior para crear el efecto
                          //de cargar e la izquiera de nuevo
                          $("#div_formularioPolizas").hide();

                          //llamo a la funcion que le da datos al formulario a partir del key del jqgrid
                          rellenar_formulario(row_id);
                          //cargo el menu lateral
                          $("[id*='leftWrapperPolizas']").load("Polizas/menuLateral_polizas.aspx");
                          //muestor el menu lateral con efecto
                          $("[id*='leftWrapperPolizas']").show(1000);
```

**Menú lateral que se abre al clickar en una fila del grid**

```
        <body>
<div id="menuPolizass">
<div id="listView" class="list listView">
            <li class="<%--list-item-active--%>"><a href="#" id="menuLateral_cliente" class='target listView'>Cliente</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="menuLateralPolizas_recibos" class='target listView'>Recibos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="menuLateralPolizas_siniestros" class='target listView'>Siniestros</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="menuLateralPolizas_tarificacion" class='target listView'>Tarificación</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="menuLateralPolizas_imprimir" class='target listView'>Imprimir</a></li>

        </div>
<div id="flotantePolizas"></div>
```

```
      function funciones_MenuLateral() {

      $("#menuLateralPolizas_recibos").unbind("click");
          $("#menuLateralPolizas_recibos").click( function () {
              if ($("#jqGridRecibos").length == 0) {
                  $("[id*='flotantePolizas']").load("Recibos/gridRecibos.aspx");


                  $("[id*='flotantePolizas']").dialog({
                      width: 1200,
                      height: 800,
                      beforeClose: function (event, ui) {
                          //al cerrar el dialog borro el jqgrid para que no haya error al volverlo a abrir
                          alert("cerrado");
                          $("#jqGridRecibos").remove();

                      }
                  }).dialogExtend({
                      "closable": true,
                      "maximizable": false,
                      "minimizable": true,
                      "collapsable": true,

                  });

                  //return false;
                  $("[id*='menuLateralPolizas_recibos']").attr('id', 'NEWID');

              }
              else {
                  alert("Esta ventana ya esta abierta");
              }
          });


  }
  funciones_MenuLateral();
```

Comment: ¿Es una aplicación web ASP.NET?, ese _menú_ que mencionas, ¿es un control C#?. **[edit] tu pregunta** con estos datos.

Comment: Podrías mostrar parte del HTML? Qué es exactamente lo que se recarga en forma asíncrona y cómo? Significa que al pinchar un elemento del menú usas ajax para refrescar el contenido de un div?

Comment: Tengo 2 menús los 2 hechos con html normal no con los controles c# ,un menú superior , desde este por ejemplo pulso en gestión de polizas, se me abre un html que es polizas.html, ese html contiene un grid con las polizas y al clicar en una fila del grid, se me abré un menú lateral desde el que puedo ir ,por ejemplos a los recibos asociados a esa poliza seleccionada en la fila del grid. Al hacer estos pasos mas de 1 vez sin refrescar la pagina cuando clico en el menu lateral del html que se abre a partir del menu superior se repite el evento click y se me abren 2 veces los recibos de esa poliza

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hola veo que usas jQuery, en este caso la solucion es muy fácil, debido a lo extenso de tu código te dare el ejemplo pero la solucion es la misma usando

```
.one() //de jQuery
```

```js
$("#menu").one("click", function (){
     //esto solo se ejecuta la primera vez que das click en el elemento con el id menu
     alert("abrir menu");
 });
```

```css
#menu{
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  min-width: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  min-height:30px;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
    
</div>
```

Mi snippet lo que hace es simple, le das click y sólo por la primera vez lanzará un alert, Lo que harás sera el cambiar tu codigo cada que añadas el evento click sólo en los lugares que quieres que este se ejecute una vez, Ejemplo:

```
$("[id*='gestion_polizas']").click(function () {
```

Este se cambia por:

```
$("[id*='gestion_polizas']").one("click",function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor seria que no bindearas dos veces el evento sobre ese elemento, pero bueno dado el caso, podrias hacer lo siguiente:

```
$( "#foo").unbind( "click" ).click(function (){
 //Tu código
});
```

Esto hará que al bindear el evento click sobre el elemento, se quite el que existiera previamente antes de bindear el nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

Vale, pues lo acabo de solucionar, no era problema de que el evento click se cargara 2 veces, el problema era que se volvia a cargar el divflotante y daba error.Lo que he hecho es hacer un #divflotante.remove cada vez que llamo a la funcion funcionesmenulateral() y así funciona correctamente

Comment: Me alegra que hayas solucionado tu problema, mi sólucion a la pregunta funciona, te pido cordialmente considerar seleccionarla como respuesta ya que soluciona la pergunta (No por ti o por mi sino por los usuarios que vengan a por la pregunta exacta y que así lo encuentren rápido). Saludos!